# JSP multiple WebServlet URL pattern with different Request Dispatch

Tags: jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

```
@WebServlet(
        name = "HomeServlet",
        description = "Homepage Servlet Configuration",
        urlPatterns = {"/HomeServlet", "/RegisterServlet"}
)
public class HomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher= request.getRequestDispatcher( "/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp" );
        dispatcher.forward( request, response );
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher= request.getRequestDispatcher( "/WEB-INF/pages/register.jsp" );
        dispatcher.forward( request, response );
    } 
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

So far i only configured my Java Servlet for HomeServlet which redirects to Index.jsp when my HTML Front End Form gets Submitted.

**EDIT:**
My question is how to redirect the specific URL pattern to my different jsp pages.

Comment: what's your question ?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: if you want to redirect to 2 different pages pass a condition to servlet
you can do it with a hidden input or a link and get this paramter in servlet ...

Comment: @Taha: WEB-INF is definitivly the correct approach as long as one does want to prohibit direct access to static files.